# How to use AppleScript’s “localized string” inside an Automator workflow

Tags: localization, applescript, automator

I have created an Automator *workflow service* (not Automator application!) under Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) whose core is an AppleScript action. The action needs to notify the user at several points about its operations (including a possible abort) and I would like the messages to be localized in the user’s language.

Following Apple‘s [string localization guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6-SW1), I have created locale resource folders inside the workflow bundle (i.e. `<bundle>/Contents/Resources/<lang>.lproj/` folders) and placed `Localizable.strings` files inside containing string mappings in UTF-16 encoding. I call these using the `localized string of <string_mapping_token>` construct of AppleScript.

This works just fine when packed into an AppleScript application bundle (tested and confirmed), but localization fails when the exact same script and structure are used inside an Automator generated service – all I get are the raw tokens (note the [localized menu names](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1605/_index.html) in `ServicesMenu.strings` are picked up just fine – the resource folder structure itself does not seem to be the problem).

My guess is the issue is that inside an Automator workflow, as opposed to an application bundle, the context of `localized string` is Automator (or Automator Runner, as it may be), not the bundle proper, and thus localization lookup fails. I have tried adding a Bundle identifier (`CFBundleIdentifier`) to the service and referring to that via Automator’s own `localized string in bundle with identifier <identifier>` construct, but that seems to be restricted to action bundles registered with Automator.

**Is there a workaround for this issue allowing me to use AppleScript’s native localization mechanism inside a self contained AppleScript service?**

Comment: It works for me - are you (re)adding the Localizable.strings file after Automator builds the application?

Comment: @Red_Menace: the problem is I am building an Automator *service*, not an Automator *application*. The latter provides a localization stub (with a dummy `.nib` file for each supported language of OS X, if I am correct) and supports localized strings if you re-add the `Localizable.strings` file to its respective `<lang>.lproj` folder after each build by Automator. The former does not provide any localization structure by itself, but you can add it manually. That works, as described in my question, for localization of service menu entries, but only for that – `Localizable.strings` are ignored.

Comment: Just a poke in the dark: You're using the short names for <lang>, such as "de" and "en", right? I just ask because that are longer names that work in _some_ cases, and if you're actually using those, maybe that's what you have to change. Other than that, no ideas.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: thanks for the suggestion – tried both long and short (I’ve seen that being an issue before, too), but it really seems to be an issue of the context for `localized string` not being the script itself in the case of Services – Red_Menace’s solution worked, though.

Comment: @kopischke link is broken, can you update?

Comment: @NulledPointer done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **localized string** command doesn't seem to have the right context in an Automator service, but you can use any bundle that has the resources in the usual places.  If you know where the bundle is (your service workflow, a containing application, etc), you can specify that path in the command, e.g.

```
get localized string of "testing" in bundle file "path:to:your:bundle"
```

EDIT: the following is an example of what works for me:

I created a new service workflow that receives text in any application, consisting of a **Run AppleScript** action:

```
property myPath : (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Services:localize test.workflow"

on run {input, parameters}

    try
        display alert getLocalizedString("TESTING") & return & getLocalizedString("NO_ERROR") message "Input Text:    " & quoted form of (input as text)
    on error errmess number errnum
        display alert "Error" & errnum message errmess
    end try

    return input
end run

on getLocalizedString(theString)
    get localized string of theString in bundle file myPath
end getLocalizedString
```

I named the workflow "localize test", and saved it in the default **~/Library/Services** folder (this is the path is in the **myPath** property).  Next, a **Localizable.strings** file (UTF-16 created with BBEdit) was placed in the service bundle in the **/Contents/Resources/English.lproj** folder that contains the following:

```
/* Automator localization test */
"NO_ERROR" = "There seems to have been no error.";
"TESTING" = "Hmmm, works OK for me...";
```

An additional test using an AppleScript script bundle on my Desktop with the same resources added also worked OK, so it looks like anything will do as long as you use a path to a valid bundle directory structure.

Comment: All that gets me is an AppleScript error: “file "path:to:my:bundle" cannot be read” (yeah, just to pre-empt the question: I am using the actual path to the bundle; tried using both an alias as text and a string literal, with and without the folder ":" terminator. No dice).

Comment: According to the Automator AS dictionary, the expected parameter `bar` in `localized string of "foo" in bundle bar` is an Automator bundle object. Running a quick test, I cannot coerce an alias or file object to such a bundle object, but I may be missing something?

Comment: I tested with both an external script bundle and the service workflow itself, with the Localizable.strings file in the appropriate .lproj folder - I created the intermediate folders, but made no other changes.   This method works for me using the path to the bundle (I just tested for English), although if using the service bundle you might have to play games to dynamically locate it.

Comment: Yes, dynamically locating the workflow is a problem of that approach – but right now, I’d settle for actually getting your solution to work. As things stand, I can’t get rid of the AppleScript error…

Comment: I edited my answer to include specifics about my working solution.

Comment: As it turns out, the AS error pops up whenever I try to run the service inside Automator. As soon as I use the service directly, the error goes away (not sure I even want to know…). Accepted and … thanks!